# What should I change to my code in order that the program draws the image seen in picture 1?

Tags: java, draw

This is the expected output:
[image]

And this is what my code produces:
[image]

This is the code. What should I change in it so that it produces the correct image?

```
package blatt03;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class LoesungKegel extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public LoesungKegel() {
    super();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(610, 417);
    this.setTitle("LÃ¶sung in der Klasse " + this.getClass().getName());
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new LoesungKegel();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int x25 = this.getWidth() / 4;
    int x75 = this.getWidth() * 3 / 4;
    int y25 = this.getHeight() / 4;
    int y75 = this.getHeight() * 3 / 4;

    double stepX = getWidth() / 40;
    double step1 = getHeight()  / 40;

    g.drawLine(x75, y25, x25, y25);

    g.drawLine(x75, y25, x25, y75);

    g.drawLine(x25, y75, x75, y75);

    g.drawLine(x25, y25, x75, y75);

    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {

         g.drawLine(x25, y25, x25/2 + (int) (stepX * i), y25/2 - (int) (step1 * i));

        g.drawLine(x25/2 + (int) (stepX * i), y25/2 - (int) (step1 * i), x75, y75);

    }

}
}
```

And not picture 2, that is what it currently shows with my code.

Comment: I'd recommend either 1) playing computer and analyze what your code is actually doing, or 2) stepping through your code in the debugger, looking at your intermediate values, and seeing if they align with what you expect.

Comment: Looks like the `y` values are constant and the `x` values are symmetrical about the midpoint; I don't think you have that here.

Comment: Hi, David. I think you're having a common problem to new programmers, which is that you're trying to do too much in a single step. I'd recommend changing those calls within the `for` loop so that you calculate coordinates in separate methods. That'll make it easier to figure out where the calculations are going wrong.

Comment: Looking at the first image, it is immediately apparent that every single line segment starts at vertical coordinate `y25` and ends at `y75` (or vice versa, if you prefer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you are trying to generate is much simpler than the code you are trying to use to generate it. It's just one end of the line going forward horizontally while the other end goes backward by the same amount. This is how you would achieve something like that (assuming you are trying to draw 40 lines).

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // fill background
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    int x25 = this.getWidth() / 4;
    int x75 = this.getWidth() * 3 / 4;
    int y25 = this.getHeight() / 4;
    int y75 = this.getHeight() * 3 / 4;

    // draw inner lines
    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    int width = x75 - x25;
    double step = width / 40.0;
    for (double i = 0; i < width; i += step) {
        g.drawLine((int)(x25 + i), y25, (int)(x75 - i), y75);
    }

    // draw outer lines
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawLine(x25, y25, x75, y25);
    g.drawLine(x25, y75, x75, y75);
    g.drawLine(x25, y25, x75, y75);
    g.drawLine(x75, y25, x25, y75);
}
```

Comment: @DavidVulpe please mark Leo's answer as answering your question if you feel it fully answers it (which I think it does).

Answer (score 0):

This is close while maintaining the gist of your approach.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int x25 = this.getWidth() / 4;
    int x75 = this.getWidth() * 3 / 4;
    int y25 = this.getHeight() / 4;
    int y75 = this.getHeight() * 3 / 4;
    int x50 = this.getWidth() / 2;
    int y50 = this.getHeight() / 2;

    int stepX = (x75 - x25) / 40;

    g.drawLine(x75, y25, x25, y25);

    g.drawLine(x75, y25, x25, y75);

    g.drawLine(x25, y75, x75, y75);

    g.drawLine(x25, y25, x75, y75);

    for (int i = 1; x25 + (i * stepX) < x75; i++) {

        g.drawLine(x50, y50, x25 + (stepX * i), y25);

        g.drawLine(x50, y50, x25 + (stepX * i), y75);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for answering !

Comment: Leo's answer is the better approach and more accurately matches your desired result.